# I want to "fill" between two extended line.new. pine-script is not having it ;√)

Tags: line, pine-script, fill

[pine-script] "Fill," between two extended lines?  line.new(bar_index[3], LAG_SHORT_CNT, & line.new(bar_index[3], LAG_SHORT_CNT7

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the current version of pinescript, maybe in the future. For now you can only use `fill()` with either `plot()` or `hline()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **plot()** instead. Draw the lines with condition:

```
plot_line1 = plot(condition_01 ? line_01 : na)
plot_line2 = plot(condition_02 ? line_02 : na)
fill(plot_line1, plot_line2)
```