# Plot Order of plots and all drawn elements like line.new or label.new

Tags: plot, pine-script

It was my understanding that the plot order was the same as the occurrence in the code.  So if I plotted a line on code line 23 it would be plotted before (and appear behind) a label that was defined from code line 98.

In a workaround to my last question, I am using a line set to 30 px and a transparency of 75 to create a fill.  The problem is it is plotting over the top of labels that are defined much later in the code and because of their location should be plotting on top of the line, but they are not.

I have searched everywhere, pine manual vs 4, Kodafy, and here on Stack to find exactly what the output order of drawing, labels, line, and plots are.

If anyone knows the solution to my specific problem or where I can find the information resources to resolve it myself I would be very grateful.

Last Post referred to above: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236171/i-want-to-fill-between-two-extended-line-new-pine-script-is-not-having-it-√/69241461#69241461](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236171/i-want-to-fill-between-two-extended-line-new-pine-script-is-not-having-it-%E2%88%9A/69241461#69241461)

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to you study() line:

explicit_plot_zorder = true

from the refman:

"explicit_plot_zorder (const bool) Specifies the order in which the indicator's plots, fills, and hlines are rendered. If true, the plots will be drawn based on the order in which they appear in the indicator's code, each newer plot being drawn above the previous ones. This only applies to plot*() functions, fill, and hline. Optional. The default is `false`."

Hope that can fix your problem

Cheers, and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: Thank you, I always assumed that was the default for pine script.  My problem was a line plotting over a label.  Apparently, "explicit_plot_zorder = true," does not apply to labels as it did not affect the line overprinting my label. Moved all labels to the very end of the script.  Thanks for your help. If you can think of another trick please share,  Michael.