# How to specify which Plot should be drawn above/after the other? (Drawing Order)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

If there are several several plots on a chart, transparent colors may darken or cover each other.

**How to specify it in Pine Script V4 vs. V5?** Like we arrange the order of layers in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257220/plot-order-of-plots-and-all-drawn-elements-like-line-new-or-label-new). An `explicit_plot_zorder = true` part must be inserted into the `study()` line. It works in Pine Script Version 4, and see in an answer below, works in V5, too.

```
study(shorttitle="SomeShortName", title="Title Text", overlay=true, resolution="", explicit_plot_zorder = true)
```

Comment: `study()` was changed to `indicator()` in v5. The v5 refman documents it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator).

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally (because it was saved in my Indicator Templates, and I duplicated that one's source code) worked based on a v4 code. Now you encouraged me to find a v5 version and manually upgrade my code.   